# In JUnit, test Activity if it did received the Extra from Intent

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

SomeActivity is below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SomeActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("id", someId);
startActivity(intent);
```

In my JUnit I would like to test `AnotherActivity` if it really did received the extra from an Intent. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using setActivityIntent though? try below code to figure it out.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.app", "com.app.Hello");
    intent.putExtra("id", "1234");
    setActivityIntent(addEvent);
```

Comment: Yeh that was what I'm trying using in my AnotherActivityTest.class but I want it done in SomeActivityTest.class. If there is no other way, maybe I'll just use that way anyway.